# Retornar a rota com o maior tempo de voo em media

Tags: python, pandas

Preciso criar uma função que indica qual rota tem o maior tempo de voo em MÉDIA.

Preciso usar as colunas 'OriginAirportName' e 'DestinationAirportName', descartando os voos cancelados e retornando uma tupla (OriginAirportName, DestinationAirportName).

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_6QB5vxN-7Jp9DqiP0opSgi3ALeD5ZUn?usp=sharing

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**As colunas utilizadas para realizar o calculo do tempo médio das rotas são:**

*CRSDepTime: a hora de partida programada*

*DepDelay: o número de minutos de atraso na partida (o voo que saiu antes do horário tem um valor negativo)*

*CRSArrTime: a hora de chegada programada*

*ArrDelay: o número de minutos de atraso na chegada (o voo que chegou antes do horário tem um valor negativo)*

*Cancelado: um indicador binário de que o voo foi cancelado*

**Até o momento, a solução que encontrei retorna erro dentro da função. Entretanto, rodando o comando fora do escopo da função, ele indica qual a maior média de tempo de voo da rota. Acho que o erro da função pode estar no retorno da tupla e o método max()**

```
df.drop(df.loc[df['Cancelled'] == 1].index, axis=0, inplace=True)
df['Time'] = (df['CRSArrTime'] - df['CRSDepTime']) + 
(df['DepDelay'] + df['ArrDelay'])
df = df.groupby(['OriginAirportName','DestAirportName']).mean().max()
def high_delay(df) -> tuple:
     return (df['OriginAirportName'], df['DestAirportName'])
high_delay(df)
```

Comment: Olá amigo. Tá um pouco difícil de te ajudar. Qual é a mensagem de erro que aparece? Tu tens um código mínimo que reproduza o problema, para que a gente tente reproduzir localmente e, então, te ajudar a achar a solução?

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_6QB5vxN-7Jp9DqiP0opSgi3ALeD5ZUn?usp=sharing

Answer (score -3):

Pelo link enviado, o DataFrame df está sendo chamado na função após ele ser transformado pela função Groupby logo acima. Ou seja, a função está sendo chamada usando como parâmetro um DataFrame diferente daquele para qual a função foi desenhada.
Ao aplicar a máscara cancelled = df[df['Cancelled'] == 1].index, nenhuma linha do df atende ao critério, então um valor False está sendo retornado. E False não tem índice.

Abri o notebook fornecido no link novamente e fiz as seguintes adições, a linha que agrupa pela média dos tempos:

```
max_time=df['Time'].max()
df[df['Time']==max_time].index
```

Retorna os aeroportos de origem e de destino com maior média.

Caso queria ver mais voos, pode classificar o DF todo pela coluna 'Time':

```
df=df.sort_values('Time',ascending=False)
```

Caso queira ver os "top 10":

```
df.head(10)
```

Entretanto, o cálculo da coluna tempo está gerando valores negativos. Suspeito que seja pelo fuso horário. Talvez você tenha que transformar as colunas de horários previstos de partida e chegada pelo fuso horário, por exemplo, transformando todos os horários em "horários de Brasília".

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, Sérgio. Mas ainda continuo com problema. Reescrevi o código, mas ainda continuo com problema.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Veja se resolve. Não consegui salvar o Notebook que você enviou.

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado Sérgio! Os valores negativos referem-se a voos que partiram ou chegaram antes do horário previsto. Por isso algumas rotas possuem os seus valores negativos, pois o costume é que os voos sejam adiantados.